# REST API Django does not show all tables in different endpoints

Tags: python, mysql, django, api, rest

I am learning REST API Django and would appreciate your patience and help in understaing the below case.

in `myproject/abcapp/forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Profile
        fields = "__all__"
       
  
class Zoo_data_2020Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Zoo_data_2020
        fields = "__all__"
```

in `myproject/abcapp/models.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class ProfileQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    pass

class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProfileQuerySet(self.model,using=self._db)


class Profile(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,max_length=200) 
    subtype=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    type=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=500)
  
    objects = ProfileManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'

        managed = False
        db_table ='profiles'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
          
      
class Zoo_data_2020QuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    pass
  
class Zoo_data_2020Manager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Zoo_data_2020QuerySet(self.model,using=self._db)

class Zoo_data_2020(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    size=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=100000000)
    weight=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=100000000)
    age=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=100000000)
    
    objects = Zoo_data_2020Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'zoo_data_2020'
        verbose_name_plural = 'zoo_data_2020s'

        managed = False
        db_table ='zoo_data_2020'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

in `myproject/abcapp/api/views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import generics, mixins, permissions
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
import json
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from abcapp.models import *
from .serializers import *


def is_json(json_data):
    try:
        real_json = json.loads(json_data)
        is_valid = True
    except ValueError:
        is_valid = False
    return is_valid


class ProfileDetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    
    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes = []
    queryset= Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'


class ProfileAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes= []
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    passed_id = None
    search_fields = ('id','name','animal')
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()


    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Profile.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            qs=qs.filter(name__icontains=query)
        return qs


  
class Zoo_data_2020DetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    
    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes = []
    queryset= Zoo_data_2020.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Zoo_data_2020Serializer
    lookup_field = ('id','name')
 

class Zoo_data_2020APIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes =[]
    authentication_classes= []
    serializer_class = Zoo_data_2020Serializer

    passed_id = None
    search_fields = ('id','name')
    queryset = Zoo_data_2020.objects.all()


    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Zoo_data_2020.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            qs=qs.filter(name__icontains=query)
        return qs
```

in `myproject/abcapp/api/serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from abcapp.models import *


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model=Profile
        fields = "__all__"
        
        read_only_fields = ['name']


class Zoo_data_2020Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Zoo_data_2020
        fields = "__all__"
        
        read_only_fields = ['name']
```

in `myproject/abcapp/api/urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProfileAPIView.as_view()),
    path('<id>/', ProfileDetailAPIView.as_view()),
    path('', Zoo_data_2020APIView.as_view()),
    path('<id>/', Zoo_data_2020DetailAPIView.as_view()),]
```

in `myproject/urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/profile/', include('abcapp.api.urls')),
    path('api/zoodata2020/', include('abcapp.api.urls')),

]
```

So when i do call `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile/` i get **data from tables Profile**, but when i do call `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/zoodata2020/` i get **data again from table Profile not Zoo_data_2020**. But when i remove from `myproject/abcapp/api/urls.py`:

```
path('', ProfileAPIView.as_view()),
path('<id>/', ProfileDetailAPIView.as_view()),
```

then it shows me data from table `Zoo_data_2020` but then i can't get data from table Profile

how to fix it ? I am sure that i am doing smth wrong in urls.py in both app and the project. So what i need to do to make endpoints seperate ? and also how to show them both?

I want to call http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile/?search=TIGER and as result to give me information from both tables profiles and zoo_data_2020 as they contain different data but about the same 'name' which is TIGER. But currently when **for example** i call http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile/?search=TIGER it just shows me data from tabel `Profile` not from `Zoo_data_2020`

Please help to understand it and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project urls.py, you don't have to refer the same app multiple times, you can do that in the app's urls.py

Give this a try

myproject/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('cfs.api.urls')),    
]
```

myproject/abcapp/api/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile', ProfileAPIView.as_view()),
    path('profile/<id>/', ProfileDetailAPIView.as_view()),
    path('zoo_data', Zoo_data_2020APIView.as_view()),
    path('zoo_data/<id>/', Zoo_data_2020DetailAPIView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: I did as you said and then run http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile/  but gives error : Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile/

Using the URLconf defined in sbdata.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    api/ profile
    api/ profile/<id>/
    api/ zoodata2020
    api/ zoodata2020/<id>/

The current path, api/profile/, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: this error started after i tried your method but it does not work. So i would not amend my answer above as othere people might want to ahve its initial consition i had. Please if you know how to fix please share here

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full error traceback, thank you

Comment: Thanks i fixed it, you forgot to put "/" after profile in path('profile', ProfileAPIView.as_view()), and the same in zoodata2020 . Thanks again for help

Comment: Oh my bad, Glad to know that you fixed it.